# Creating several linear models simultaneously from tidy data in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, tidyverse

I have a dataset that looks like the following.

```
id  samediff  gainloss  factor  value
1   S         G         give    3
1   S         G         impact  4
2   S         L         give    2
2   S         L         impact  5   
3   D         G         give    1
3   D         G         impact  4
4   D         L         give    3
4   D         L         impact  5
```

I would like to create a linear model for each factor to test for an interaction between the samediff variables and the gainloss variables. When I try the following code, the output I get only includes coefficients and does not include complete information for each linear model (specifically the information given when writing summary(lm) for a model).

Attempt 1:

```
lm <- dff %>%
  split(.$factor) %>%
  map(~lm(value~(samediff*gainloss), .x))
lm
```

Attempt 2:

```
lm2 <- dff %>% 
  group_by(factor) %>%
  summarise(lm = list(lm(value~(samediff*gainloss))))
lm3<-lm2$lm; names(lm3) <- lm2$factor
lm3
```

The full dataset includes many more factors than are included here. How do I adjust this so that I get the summary() output for each model produced?

Comment: Do you really want the `tidyverse` or will base R do it?

Comment: I try to stay consistent in using the tidyverse, but I'd be very happy with either at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do with base R, here is one way.

```
lm_list <- lapply(split(dff, dff$factor), function(DF) lm(value ~ samediff*gainloss, DF))
```

Then you can run, for instance,

```
lapply(lm_list, coef)
lapply(lm_list, summary)
```